# Django Docker media files save and restore

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi there I am trying to deploy a project in docker with django and django rest framework. According to the documentation I successfully able to deploy it and it is working fine with media files. I am able to upload media files (images) and it also shows the right file at the right side. But the problem is for some changes I need to re-build the container with new code ... after re-deploying It can not able to found out the previously uploaded media files(images). I badly need help on it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gttsg.png)
this is my docker-compose file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDuMJ.png)
and dockerfile

Comment: I think you forgot to copy the media files in Dockefile

Comment: how can I do that